# Wire with ability to "boost" electron current, benefits to signal propagation?

Tags: electrical-engineering

A wire that can "boost" its signal with electrons fed into it along the way, is it in any way able to propagate a signal *further*, than a wire that had to feed all its current into it at the beginning? Assume wire conductance or diameter or length does not change.

Comment: See this post here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/502860/152903

Comment: How will you know when to feed electrons in and when to take them out? How will the electrons get back to your add-in point to complete the circuit?

Answer (score 0):

what you are proposing is a *distributed* amplifier, which physically not possible in practice, as you have described it. What is done instead is to position individual or *lumped* amplifiers at intervals along the length of the transmission line, which sense the incoming signals, boost their strength, and then feed them back into the next segment of wire along the line.

Comment: note my edit. -Niels